# Integration using variable formula

Tags: integration

Prove that this are correct using the change variable formula

(a) $dA = r\ dr\ dθ$

(b) $dV = r dr\ dθ\ dz$

(c) $dV = ρ^2 \sinφ\ dρ\ dθ\ dφ$

Comment: Have you tried computing the Jacobian?

Comment: Yes, but I still have issue proving it

Comment: To compute the Jacobian, you need to be able to compute partial derivatives, and compute determinants. Which one are you having a hard time with?

Answer (score 0):

Let's put a symbol in that might be a bit intimidating: $\mathrm{d}A = \mathrm{d}x\wedge \mathrm{d}y$. You can write $\mathrm{d}A = \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$ if you want, but it's a bit more convenient to use $\wedge$, as it captures the notion that the differential area element can be positive or negative, as one of its properties is $\mathrm{d}x\wedge \mathrm{d}y = -\mathrm{d}y\wedge\mathrm{d}y$. Then, as $x = r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$,
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}x &= \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\mathrm{d}r + \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\mathrm{d}\theta = \cos(\theta)\mathrm{d}r  - r\sin(\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta \\
\mathrm{d}y &= \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\mathrm{d}r + \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}\mathrm{d}\theta = \sin(\theta)\mathrm{d}r  + r\cos(\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta 
\end{align}
You can treat '$\wedge$' almost like multiplication, as $(\mathrm{d}a+\mathrm{d}b)\wedge\mathrm{d}c = \mathrm{d}a\wedge \mathrm{d}c + \mathrm{d}b\wedge \mathrm{d}c$. Then
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}A &= \mathrm{d}x\wedge \mathrm{d}y = (\cos(\theta)\mathrm{d}r  - r\sin(\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta)\wedge ( \sin(\theta)\mathrm{d}r  + r\cos(\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta)\\
&=\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)\mathrm{d}r\wedge \mathrm{d}r - r\sin(\theta)^{2}\mathrm{d}\theta\wedge \mathrm{d}r + r\cos(\theta)^{2}\mathrm{d}r\wedge\mathrm{d}\theta -r^{2}\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta \wedge \mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= r\cos(\theta)^{2}\mathrm{d}r\wedge\mathrm{d}\theta + r\sin(\theta)^{2}\mathrm{d}r\wedge\mathrm{d}\theta  \\
&= r\mathrm{d}r\wedge\mathrm{d}\theta,
\end{align}
which we will write as $r\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta$.

You should be able to get (ii) by using $\mathrm{d}V = \mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}y\wedge\mathrm{d}z$. Is this enough to get you to (iii)?

Comment: Yes, and thank you

Comment: Do you understand why $\mathrm{d}r \wedge \mathrm{d}r = 0$?

Comment: No , please explain

Comment: Since $\mathrm{d}a\wedge \mathrm{d}b = -\mathrm{d}b\wedge \mathrm{d}a$, then $\mathrm{d}r\wedge \mathrm{d}r = -\mathrm{d}r\wedge \mathrm{d}r \implies \mathrm{d}r\wedge \mathrm{d}r = 0$.